# Set Offset = +75 minutes in Sales Order saved search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

How do I set Offset = +75 minutes (this is for cancellation reasons) in SalesOrder saved search in NetSuite , can you provide me in any detail by applying any filters?

I tried by using filters in criteria  , but I haven't seen any offset kind of field.

Comment: Can you offer more detail on what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by "offset +75 minutes"?

Comment: am trying to  retrieve all the new Sales Orders from NetSuite based on the LastModificationDate by using a Saved Search
Status of Sales Order = “Pending Fulfillment”
Offset = +75 minutes (this is for cancellation reasons)
Location = “not null” , and then once this is  Processed will translate the Sales Orders into the appropriate format, and send to the "XYZ " API

Comment: Let's take this use case". if you are adding any food item in Zomato , you ordered but you want to delete item for some reason zomato will give you 1 min time right ? IN the same way here offset is +75 minutes,  if they didn't cancel even if above 75 minuted then only I should take that salesorder into consideration

Comment: To be clear, you want the results of a saved search to return orders that were created or modified within the last 75 minutes?

Example use case - time NOW is 17:00. You only want to return orders that were created/changed from 75 minutes before (so, in other words, 15:45?)

Comment: yes:  created 75 mins before AND updated based on the last execution datetime
in detail - for example if an order was created 17:00, we only want to export this order whistl AFTER 75 minutes, meaning at 18:15.

Comment: Any idea on above please ?

Comment: I appreciate your input and will be waiting for your answer

Comment: I have tried the approach you mentioned. I added it in the criteria tab and also in the results tab to view the records in my saved search results. The last modified date is 07/03/2023 2:29 PM. I labeled the field for Formula (numeric )= ({today} - {lastmodifieddate}) * 1440 as 'TIME DIFFERENCE' and the value I see in the saved search record result is 132,566.966666666666666666666666666666667. I don't understand why it is displayed in that format instead of minutes. Any input on this would be appreciated. Additionally, I wanted to ask about my previous question... –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon running tests, I believe the following output is what you need:

[image]

The above is achieved by adding the following in the RESULTS subtab:
[image]

That is:

- FIELD = Formula (Numeric)
- FUNCTION = Number as Time
- FORMULA = ({today} - {lastmodifieddate}) * 1440

In this example, TODAYs date is compared against the LAST MODIFIED date of the record to output the time difference in minutes.

For your requirement, you want to only return records where the time difference is GREATER THAN 75 minutes; thus you will need to add the following as a filter in your saved search:

- Click the CRITERIA subtab

  - Filter = FORMULA (numeric)
  - Description = IS GREATER THAN 75
  - Formula = ({today} - {lastmodifieddate}) * 1440

If you are seeking to track the DATE CREATION of record, then change {lastmodifieddate} to {datecreated} accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try it and let you know 
Additionally , May I kindly ask you how to retrieve those (above output picture) all the  fields(today's date and time diff in minutes) in NetSuite saved search Results ?

Comment: I have tried the approach you mentioned. I added it in the criteria tab and also in the results tab to view the records in my saved search results. The last modified date is 07/03/2023 2:29 PM. I labeled the field for Formula (numeric )= ({today} - {lastmodifieddate}) * 1440 as 'TIME DIFFERENCE' and the value I see in the saved search record result is 132,566.966666666666666666666666666666667. I don't understand why it is displayed in that format instead of minutes. Any input on this would be appreciated. Additionally, I wanted to ask about my previous question...

Comment: Hi - I have updated my answer with the solution for the RESULTS subtab.
If this satisfies your needs, please upvote and mark this answer as CORRECT.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. 
One last question is How can I set the today's date and time as you did in your picture by same format as last modified date ?
I have tried it by. Formula (Text) : {today}
and I can see it as - 2023-06-07 16:21:41.0
But I need to get it as same last modified date format : 07/03/2023 2:29 PM

Comment: Instead of "Formula (Text)", Select "Formula (Date/Time)" and set {today} as the formula. The format will auto-set.